# how to dynamic headings when to export in maatwebsite/excel 3.1 in laravel

Tags: laravel

```
class ExportPrescriptionReports implements FromCollection, WithHeadings
{

    protected $names; 

    protected $start_date;

    protected $end_date;

    protected $names_count;

    public function __construct(array $names, $start_date, $end_date)
    {

        $this->names = $names;

        $this->start_date = $start_date; 

        $this->end_date = $end_date;

        $this->names_count = count($names);
    }


    public function collection()
    {
        if($this->names_count == 2){

          $name = $this->names[0];

          $name1 = $this->names[1];

          return Rsm_Prescription::select($name, $name1)
               ->where([
                   ['start_data_time', $this->start_date],
                   ['end_data_time', $this->end_date],
               ])->get();
        }
    }

    public function headings(): array
    {

    return [
            'SL No',
            'Total Rx',
            'Total Target Rx',
        ];
    }
}
```

how to dynamic the headings function like below

```
public function headings(): array

{

  return [

         $sl_no=0,

         foreach($this->names as $name){

             echo $sl_no;

             echo $name;

             $sl_no++;

          }

       ]

  }
```

Is it possible in maatwebsite-excel package in laravel? Please any one help me.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDZ5Z.png)

Comment: Hi. Put code between `\`\`\`` and not in image.

Comment: qrabno - you know any solution.

Comment: No, probably not. The question is just too bad. The best thing would be for you to make a complete example of what I could try myself! So with input, compile commands, output, error stacktrace etc.

Comment: qrabno - already I do that , thanks for response